# SQL: select from t1 all rows for which there's no corresponding in t2

Tags: sql

Let's say I have a table t1 with only one column: `id`, and I have a table t2 with two columns: `id` and `Memo`. I need to select those `id` from t1, for which there is NO row in t2 that satisfies both of the following two conditions `t1.id = t2.id` and `t2.Memo = 'myText'`. How can I do that? I have tried using `join`, but that selects row that do satisfy some conditions, whereas I need the opposite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
  FROM t1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                     FROM t2
                    WHERE t2.id = t1.id
                      AND t2.Memo = 'myText')
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is using `LEFT JOIN`:

```
select id
from t1
left join t2
  on t1.id = t2.id and t2.Memo = 'myText'
where t2.id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not good in understanding your question:

You mean those t1.id EXISTS in t2 BUT the corresponding t2.Memo <> 'myText'?

```
SELECT t1.id FROM t1 JOIN t2 
ON t1.id = t2.id
HAVING t1.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM t2 WHERE Memo = 'myText');
```

Or all t1.id either NOT EXISTS in t2 or EXISTS but Memo <> 'myText'?

```
SELECT id FROM t1 WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM t2 WHERE Memo = 'myText');
```

Comment: NOT IN can be a bit surprising if a NULL value suddenly is returned from the sub-query. (Perhaps id is NOT NULL, who knows...) NOT EXISTS is "null-safe".

Comment: Agree (though I never though "id" field should be nullable in schema design). But I want to ask if using NOT EXISTS in the way "Correct answer" does, every row in t1 will initiate one sub-query and that means if we have 1M records in t1 we need to run 1M sub-queries. Am I correct? Any better method?

Comment: That depends on the dbms optimizer. (No dbms tagged in this question.) I'd guess most major dbms products can transform NOT EXISTS and NOT IN to the same code.

Comment: Having a quick check on MySQL using EXPLAIN, the NOT EXISTS should be bad on large number of records. By the way, @w0lf gave a good answer that can execute efficiently if the fields are properly indexed.